# Updating links upon site migration of https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, links

Many links on the SE physics site presently go to my old web address:

*[http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Eneum)* and 
*[https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Eneum)*

This web site migrated to a new place,

*http://arnold-neumaier.at*

I'd therefore like to ask the moderators to update all affected URLs.

I'd also like to have corresponding changes on the other SE sites where I was posting.

Comment: This should be possible. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314169/334566 Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375122/334566

Comment: As one of the links in PM2Ring's comment indicates, SE might do this (but simple moderators cannot, there is no tool available to us for this). I've reached out to SE to ask whether this meta post is sufficient or whether there's anything else they need.

Comment: You have about forty such links, which seems like enough that non-bumping edits might be appropriate. I’ve tagged for SE attention. (Oh hello @ACuriousMind, we are responding simultaneously.)

Comment: Here is a [search showing also the links on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3a%22*mat.univie.ac.at%2f~neum*%22&pagesize=50&page=2) - such as [math.se], [scicomp.se], etc.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for raising this one to our attention. We've now executed the requested change. As with all link replacements, we do expect a bit of routine cleanup work, so be on the lookout for any cases that look odd.

As usual, let us know if you run into any major fallout as a result of the change and we'll see what we can do to help.

Comment: It seems that about 20 posts still have the "old" links. (See the list in the other answer.) Those can only be edited manually? Or was it some kind of mistake? And what about the links  on other sites - those remain for manual edits, too? (Sorry for bothering you with similar questions as on another site.)

Comment: @Martin I've reported this as a bug with the tool internally.

Comment: Putting the bug and the missed links aside, are there plans to run the replacement on other sites, too? Or was this intended to be done only on [physics.se]? Judging [by the search results](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3amat.univie.ac.at%2f~neum&pagesize=50&page=2), there are quite a few posts on other sites. AFAICT, the Community user [only edited posts on Physics](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1610076/edits-with-the-given-word-in-the-summary-user-and-date-range-multisite?num=1000&accountid=-1&Date1=2022-06-22&Date2=2022-06-24&keyword=univie.ac.at).

Comment: @Martin It should've been run network-wide; probably, however, I'll ask for a re-run once the tool is fixed so it's not skipping links.

Comment: @Martin bug is fixed and was re-run on all non-meta sites, should be good to go, but let us know if anything is still amiss

Answer (score 2):

**Redirect**

I have noticed that links to this domain are redirected to the new domain. For example, take this question: [Can you represent neutron as stable superposition of decay products?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/592907) (the [current revision](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/592907/1)).
It contains link to [https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/physfaq/topics/unstable.html](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Eneum/physfaq/topics/unstable.html) - and after clicking on the link I am redirected to: https://arnold-neumaier.at/physfaq/topics/unstable.html

Are the links supposed to be replaced even if the redirect is working?

**Other Stack Exchange sites**

It seems that some links [have been edited by the Community user](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/1067159/list-of-all-edits-where-edit-summary-contains-given-keyword?keyword=univie.ac.at) - but I do not see any edits [on other sites](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1610076/edits-with-the-given-word-in-the-summary-user-and-date-range-multisite?num=1000&accountid=-1&Date1=2022-06-22&Date2=2022-06-24&keyword=univie.ac.at). (Both queries return 53 posts - the first one searches only on Physics, the second one is network-wide.)
Was this on purpose? Are the links on other sites supposed to be edited manually?

[Searching for url:"*mat.univie.ac.at/~neum*"](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3a%22%2Amat.univie.ac.at%2f%7Eneum%2A%22&pagesize=50&page=2) returns 57 posts at the moment.

**Remaining posts on Physics**

It seems that there are still some posts here on Physics Stack Exchange. At least, I am getting some links from [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/1585616/posts-containing-the-given-word-id-and-body?word=mat.univie.ac.at/%7Eneum) and [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/1585616/posts-containing-the-given-word-id-and-body?word=mat.univie.ac.at%2F%5B%25%5D7Eneum). (Although those posts are found through [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info), I did not know how to modify [search on this site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3a%22%2Amat.univie.ac.at%2f%7Eneum%2A%22) to find such posts. At least some of them are shown if I [search for `%7Eneum`](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22*mat.univie.ac.at%2F%257Eneum*%22) rather than `~neum`. [Searching for url:mat.univie.ac.at url:neum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Amat.univie.ac.at+url%3Aneum) - as suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379940/what-is-a-reliable-way-to-search-for-urls-containing-tilde/379942#379942) - returns only 6 results, too.)

Was this just an oversight? Or the bulk replacement tool cannot edit those links? Are they supposed to be edited manually?

These are the links from the above queries - I have checked that at the time of posting this answer they contained the "old" link:

- [Phase plots: The exact particular solution is a function of time, can't find fixed points. Now, in this situation, how to draw phase plots?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/632610#633122)
- [Can you represent neutron as stable superposition of decay products?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/592907)
- [How can I estimate a confidence interval for experimental results with only one run?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/588446#591507)
- [Where is the evidence that the electron is pointlike?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/277565#277597)
- [What is $\phi(x)|0\rangle$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/193506/edit)
- [Probability vs. degree of belief in facts of nature (""Plausibility"")](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/32769)
- [Why are particles different sizes?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/32085)
- [What is a tensor?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/32028)
- [What are some critiques of Jaynes' approach to statistical mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/26825)
- [Concept of a point particle in quantum mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/24586)
- [Does locality emerge from (classical) Lagrangian mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/23094)
- [Entanglement and relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/22819)
- [Do ""shape"" and ""volume"" in ""space"" have any meaning for an electron?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/22610)
- [Suggested reading for renormalization (not only in QFT)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/22522)
- [Is QFT mathematically self-consistent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/22521)
- [Is the form of the Lagrangian relevant before the renormalization procedure?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/22515)
- [What does the appearance of a classical particle fundamentally reduce to?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/22428)
- [Are there books on Regularization and Renormalization in QFT at an Introductory level?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/22421)
- [The nature of time, according to quantum field theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/22366)
- [Are W & Z bosons virtual or not?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/22029)
- [Is the quantum analog of a probability distribution the wave function or the density matrix?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/22019)
- [Energy Measurements in a Two Fermion Double Well System](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/21810)
- [Electrons - What is Waving?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/21800)
- [In layman's terms, what is a quantum fluctuation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/21745)